# String to Timedelta Python

Tags: python, string, datetime, unicode

I'm trying to convert a string (well, unicode) in the following format to a timedelta or datetime object,

```
u'2015-05-06 12:48:37 UTC+00:00'
```

I can't find anywhere with the timezone included and

```
datetime.strptime('2015-05-06 12:48:37', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M-%S')
```

without the timezone is throwing a does not match format error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Also an explaination of the formatting would be great.

Comment: @Kasramvd - Not a duplicate; the one without a timezone fails because of a formatting error (delimiting the seconds with `'-'` instead of `':'`).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes not exactly but I think OP can find the answer in dup question!

Comment: Aahh the dash, thanks @Kasramvd